# Does every graph admit an embedding such that identically-colored edges do not cross?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Given a graph, is it always possible to color the edges of the graph using two colors such that there exists an embedding of the graph in the plane where only opposite-colored edges cross?

Simple counting arguments from lower bounds on the pair-crossing number have failed me so far; I have also not had luck finding information on graphs with maximal crossing number for a given number edges.

Extension: if it is not always possible with two colors, what is the minimal number of colors required such that it is always possible? Is it constant?

Comment: It is not always possible with two colours since an $n$-vertex planar graph has at most $3n-6$ edges, and the red subgraph and blue subgraph are both planar graphs.  So, any $n$-vertex graph with at least $6n-11$ edges is a counterexample.

Comment: Seems related to graph thickness?

Comment: I think the minimum number of colours is sometimes called geometric thickness.

Comment: Ah yes, thinking of it as the union of planar subgraphs does make the structure of the problem much clearer. Seems obvious now, but thank you for the tip

Comment: If your problem is solved, you could answer your own question and accept the answer, so that it does not stay "unanswered".

Comment: Ramsey's theorem tells us that for any fixed number of colors a sufficiently large complete graph will contain a monochromatic $K_5$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested by Jukka Kohonen, I'll turn my comment into an answer.

The answer is in general **no**.   If such an embedding exists, then the red subgraph and blue subgraph are both planar. However, every $n$-vertex planar graph has at most $3n-6$ edges.  So, any $n$-vertex graph with at least $6n-11$ edges is a counterexample.

The minimum number of colours required for such an embedding is often called *geometric thickness*.  For example, geometric thickness is mentioned on the Wikipedia page for [graph thickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thickness_(graph_theory)), which is the minimum number of planar subgraphs that partition the edge set of a graph (where the embedding is not necessarily the same for each planar subgraph).

Comment: Does it make a difference if the vertex positions are required to be the same in the two embeddings? This would better match the OP's problem statement.

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference.  Geometric thickness is what the OP is asking about, while thickness is a related but different parameter (since the embeddings do not have to be the same).